# Можно ли в цитате изменять структуру предложения, сохраняя смысл?

Tags: цитата

Известная цитата из "Евгения Онегина" А. С. Пушкина:

```
Они сошлись. Волна и камень,
Стихи и проза, лед и пламень
Не столь различны меж собой.
```

Разумеется, смысл этих строк в том, что главные герои, Онегин и Ленский, были даже **более** "различны меж собой", чем такие противоположности, как "волна и камень, стихи и проза, лед и пламень". Однако Александр Пушкин не употребляет сравнительного оборота напрямую, хотя, безусловно, подразумевается: "Не столь различны меж собой, *[как Ленский и Онегин]*".

Вопрос заключается в том, можно ли в своем тексте процитировать эти строки так: "Главные герои были полными противоположностями: "Волна и камень, Стихи и проза, лед и пламень..."?

С одной стороны, по моему мнению, смысл цитаты сохраняется. С другой стороны, цитируя подобным образом, мы **напрямую** сравниваем героев с водой и пламенем, а Пушкин говорил, что "вода и пламень, НЕ СТОЛЬ различны меж собой", то есть даже менее противоположны.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что лучше привести **цитату полностью.**

Главные герои были полными противоположностями: "*Волна и камень,
Стихи и проза, лед и пламень Не столь различны меж собой*".

Смысл очевиден: герои различны ***даже в большей степени***, чем эти стихии.

Comment: А можно в цитате писать большую букву в начале новой строки?

Comment: Посмотрите пример  со стихами у Розенталя http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=164#pp164 , Грамота.ру http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/54-kav1 (строчные и прописные буквы), и еще один источник http://russkiy-na-5.ru/articles/449 (три способа оформления стихов).

Comment: Мне кажется,что ваш вариант лучше оформить в строку, как у меня написано.